# Django - how to perform delete object using a view

Tags: django

This is my code in my html

```
{% for summary in psummary %}
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="tdcell">{{summary.Description}}</td>
<td colspan="2" class="tdcell">{{summary.Start_Grading_Period}}</td>
<td colspan="2" class="tdcell">{{summary.End_Grading_Period}}</td>
<td colspan="2" class="tdcell">{{summary.Method}}</td>
<td colspan="3" class="tdcell"><span style="text-align: right;font-weight: 600;" class="close" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><a href="url:delete_view">&times;</a></span></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

this is how it looks like

[image]

this is my views.py

```
def function(request,part_id =None):
    object = gradingPeriodsSummary.objects.get(id=part_id)
    object.delete()

    print(object)
    return render(request, 'admin/Homepage/view.html')
```

urls.py

```
path('delete/(?P<part_id>[0-9]+)/$', Homepage.views.function, name='delete_view'),
```

i just want that if the teacher click the close button it will delete the record in the database

i followed the instruction here, but its not working 
[Django - How to delete a object directly from a button in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248228/django-how-to-delete-a-object-directly-from-a-button-in-a-table?fbclid=IwAR0hBArJt3nOTC3uj7XRDoGRFPx_piArYF4_XZsB6-W0pY8rrRq1pJZFLdc)

Comment: You will get an error on `print(object)` as it's .... deleted.
Beside that, your code looks correct, what's the matter?

Comment: i dont receive an error, but the data didnt delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the `id` to the `URL`. Try adding the id to your link:

```
<a href="{% url "delete_view" summary.id %}" >&times;</a>
```

Comment: i copy your solution sir, but the record still exist when i delete the record in the html

Comment: You can try the above, change the url definition but still pass the `id`

Comment: Update your `href` attribute to the example in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

wrong url definition href="url:delete_view" must be href="{% url "delete_view" summary.id %}", use this

```
<td colspan="3" class="tdcell"><span style="text-align: right;font-weight: 600;" class="close" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><a href="{% url "delete_view" summary.id %}">&times;</a></span></td>
```

instead of using

```
<td colspan="3" class="tdcell"><span style="text-align: right;font-weight: 600;" class="close" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><a href="url:delete_view">&times;</a></span></td>
```